# API Key Authentication In ASP.NET Core and Role based authorization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, api-key

I read and saw many tutorials how to apply API key auth to web api (both controller or minimalapi).

What I'm asking if it makes sense to have several (2 or 3) different apikeys, bound to different Roles (eg. onlyReader, fulluser, admin) and then allow/disallow some endpoints based to that role/key.

Any sample to show?

Basically... if I have different users with different rights, have I to implement JWT because Api key is not the right solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of issue or obstacle you are facing.

based on my assumption,
e.g.

you can add multiple roles in claims

```
var user = authSerivces.AuthenticateUser(loginUser.Username, loginUser.Password);
    if (user == null)
        throw new ApiException("Invalid Login Credentials: " + bus.ErrorMessage, 401);

    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim("username",loginUser.Username));
    claims.Add(new Claim("displayname",loginUser.Name));
    
    // Add roles as multiple claims
    foreach(var role in user.Roles) 
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
    } 
    


var token = JwtHelper.GetJwtToken(
    loginUser.Username,
    Configuration.JwtToken.SigningKey,
    Configuration.JwtToken.Issuer,
    Configuration.JwtToken.Audience,
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Configuration.JwtToken.TokenTimeoutMinutes),
    claims.ToArray());
```

And You can validate with role checks

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("customers")]
public async Task<SaveResponseModel> SaveCustomer(IdvCustomer model)
```

Comment: yes, involving JWT it is clear that I can; my question was if using the only and pure API key auth, if it was possible. thanks for your sample, anyway.